# Get Random Selection of Rows Equal Number Per Grouping

Tags: sql-server-2005, t-sql, sql-server-2000

I have a table, `SCCalls`, which has a column `Call_CalT_Code`. `Call_CalT_Code` can be one of several different values. It also has a column `Call_InDate` which I will be filtering by.

I need to get 1000 random records (filtered by `Call_InDate`) in total, distributed equally number for each `Call_CalT_Code`.

How can I do this?

Edit (gbn): solution has to work on a database that is compatibility mode 80 on SQL Server 2005

Comment: It's trickier with SQL Server 2000. Are you sure the tag is correct? And is this "1000 per Call_CalT_Code" or "1000 in total". It isn't clear.. and the 2 requests are mutually exclusive...

Comment: Yes, data is on 2000. It's copied nightly onto a 2005 server, but that runs in 2000 compatibility mode (i know!).

Comment: @gbn, it's 1000 in total, feel free to edit to make it clearer, not sure how i can.

Comment: This means it's still SQL Server 2005 except for a few oddities

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may need to play around with the numbers in the division.

If you have 9 values, then 1000/9 = 111 so you'd only get 999 rows back. So I used 1100 and a later TOP 1000.

```
SELECT TOP 1000
   *
FROM
   (
   SELECT
       *,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Call_CalT_Code ORDER BY NEWID()) AS rn
    FROM
       MyTable
      ) foo
WHERE
    rn <= 1100 / (SELECT COUNT(distinct Call_CalT_Code) FROM MyTable)
ORDER BY
    rn
```